# Compact sets in TVS

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact subset of a Hausdorff topological vector space. Is it true that
$\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}K$ is either empty of or is a set consisting of the origin only?

Comment: No. Think about $\mathbb{Q}_p.$ Also please post this level of question on Math.StackExchange.com 

Comment: @JSpecter: very often by "TVS" one understands "TVS over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$". If the OP meant "TVS over a local field", he would have probably specified it.

Comment: It really looks like a homework in a functional analysis course...

Comment: @Alain: maybe you're right. 

Answer (score 6):

I'll assume this is a TVS over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and not over some other local field.

If $x$ is nonzero and belongs to $\frac1{n}K$ for every $n \geq 1$, then $nx \in K$ for each $n$. If $L$ is the line through $x$, then the subspace topology coincides with the standard topology on the ground field by the TVS axioms, and $L \cap K$ is a compact subset of the line which is unbounded since it contains all the $nx$. This gives a contradiction.